# Radio Buttons Switch Checked php

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button, checked

My site is like a search engine with 2 types of search. Type 1 Type 2.
I just dont know how to do it when someone come to my site the default checked type to be Type 1 and if it choose Type2 then remain Type2 for the visitor even if the page is refreshed.
What i need exactly is like sample from here.

js

```
$(function() {
        $( "#radio" ).buttonset();
    });​
```

html

```
<form>
    <div id="radio">
        <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" /><label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" checked="checked" /><label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" /><label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to be able to switch the **checked="checked"** from a radio to another or something like this i think. Really don't know. But i think it has to do something with php or javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to cache/store the set option somewhere (cookie, database, memcache(d), redis, etc.) and load using the user's ID. This will also have to be handled in Javascript as it involves the client-side.

**Cookie Reference**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie

For memcache(d), redis, SQL, file storage:

**AJAX Reference**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX

Comment: So i think i will have to open another post on how to set this cookies because i never worked with them

Answer (score 1):

you can define function in the onClick event of the radio button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('radio[name=radio]').each(function() {
   $(this).click(function() {
    my_function();
    });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

and my_function will send an ajax request to open session to keep the value of checked radio:

```
my_function()
{
   var value_checked = $("input[name='radio']:checked").val();
   $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'page.php',
   data: {'value_checked':value_checked},
   });
}
```

you get in your page.php $_POST['value_checked '] and you set it in a session variable

Answer (score 0):

You have to store that information in a cookie or a session as **web is stateless** and it will not remember the status of the page if posted back unless it is cached somewhere..

Try using the [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)